# Отсутствие перевода про дату рождения на странице редактирования профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице редактирования профиля отсутствует перевод названия поля с указанием даты рождения:

> Birthday (only used for displaying age)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод:

> Дата рождения (используется только для отображения возраста)