# Отсутствие перевода поля имени в профиле

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Примерно месяц назад в профиле было [обнаружено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3443/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F) отсутствие перевода про дату рождения. По дате перевод появился, но почему-то теперь съехала инфа по имени пользователя:

> Full name

[image: fullname]

Какой там был раньше перевод (и было ли вообще это поле), я сейчас затрудняюсь ответить, но предлагаю вариант:

> Полное имя